# Jodd Jerry (java): how to get the contents of node itself?

Tags: java, jquery, jodd, jodd-lagarto

Using [Jodd Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/), how to get the contents of node itself? (Jodd jerry is Java utilility)

Like jQuery:

```
$("selector").prop('outerHTML')
```

Comment: `$("selector").text()` or `$("selector").html()`

Comment: can't,   $("selector").text()=""  ,$("selector").html()=""

Comment: try $("selector").outerHTML;

Comment: It will be useful to go through official api's http://api.jquery.com/html/ and http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @senz: well then your selector is wrong. or you are getting the element before it is loaded

Comment: @Satpal : ok but it has worked for me .. like `$("selector").get(0).outerHTML`

Comment: @Satpal ok can you explain please. thanks

Comment: @YoYo, `.get(0)` returns underlying DOM element which has `outerHTML` property hence it works. https://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Thanks ......  @Satpal

Comment: @ALL sorry, i dont use jquery,jquery it is ok, i use Jodd jerry it is Java utils

Comment: String contents = jerry.$("selector").get(0).getHtml(); it is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String contents = jerry.$("selector").get(0).getHtml();
Node node = jerry.$("selector").get(0);   
String html = node.getHtml()
```

node has getHmtl()

Comment: Hey @senz, is this different from how jQuery is working - i.e. why `html()` is not working for you? If you think this is an issue, please raise the issue on github.